# How to read a unique id from a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have this private void which handles incoming persons. These persons are searched by their birthdays. The birthday of the person I find, I add its name and number into a `JComboBox`.

However, another button should read the `ID` of the selected person. How can I do that?

```
String birthday= tfBirthday.getText();
personQuery query = Application.getPersonQuery();
List<Person> persons= query.getPerson(birthday);

for(int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++){
                Person person = persons.get(i);
                tfcSelectName.addItem(person.getPersonID() + " " + person.getPersonName() + " "+ person.getPersonLastName());
}
```

How can i read somehow the person.getPersonID when from the added items in the combobox?

THanx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the toString() method in your person class and then add the Person objects directly into the combo box. then, when you retrieve the selected item you cast the object to Person and use the method to get the id.

In your person class:

```
public String toString() {
   return (person.getPersonID() + " " + person.getPersonName() + " "+ person.getPersonLastName()
}
```

then the code you added in the question can change to:

```
String birthday= tfBirthday.getText();
personQuery query = Application.getPersonQuery();
List<Person> persons= query.getPerson(birthday);

for(int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++){
    tfcSelectName.addItem(persons.get(i));
}
```

later in the action performed code of the button you mentioned, you can do:

```
Person selectedPerson = (Person)tfcSelectName.getSelectedItem();
```

and you have the person object and you can call person.getPersonID() to get the ID.

Comment: Changing the toString method of an Object for a single use case is ill advised. You should be supplying a ListCellRenderer for the combo box to customize the view for this use case, and should be replying on the examining the Person properties of the selected object when the selection changes

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are absolutely right. I add this comment to encourage any one who references this in future to supply a ListCellRenderer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not (and cannot unless you parse the string) read the IDs from the `JComboBox`, instead you should read it directly from the list of persons, just as you did in the code you posted.